# Pyautocad iter object stops iteration

Tags: python-3.x, autocad-scripts

I have this error why? I have something like 2000 text and it just stop iterating after several one.

```
from pyautocad import Autocad
import comtypes
import regex, time
acad = Autocad()
textGroup = []
    
for i in acad.doc.Modelspace:
    print(i.ObjectName)
    time.sleep(0.01)
```

[image]